# jenkins deployment making the build very slow

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, json, yaml

I am new to Jenkins. I am doing a build through Jenkins, but the build is very slow. Is there any way I can speed it up?

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('cplib') _

import com.sports.paas.cplib.helpers.Build
import com.sports.paas.cplib.helpers.Workspace
import com.sports.paas.cplib.utils.Openshift

def bld = new Build()
def wspace = new Workspace()   
def osh = new Openshift()
def appReleaseTag = ""

def NODE_HOME = "${JENKINS_HOME_SLAVE}/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_6.11.1"
def projectName = "player"
def appName = "ball"
def appOcpConfigBranch = "master"


// ########################################################################################
// PIPELINE WORKFLOW
// ########################################################################################
pipeline {

    agent { node('nodejs')}
    tools {
        nodejs 'nodejs-8.11.2'
    }

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30', daysToKeepStr: '15'))
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
        timestamps()
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
    }

    parameters {
        choice (
            name : 'DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT',
            choices: ' \nunit\ntest\nstage',
            description: '[Required] Select the location to deploy.'
        )
    }


    stages {

        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                script {
                    log.info "Explicit scm checkout ..."
                    checkout scm
                    wspace.init()
                // wspace.checkoutAppOcpConfig(appName, appOcpConfigBranch)
                    appReleaseTag = wspace.getBuildProperty("version") + "." + env.BUILD_NUMBER
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build Artifacts') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                        echo "Building artifacts ..."
                        export PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME/bin;
                        echo "Running node build ..."
                        # Please build your application using npm or yarn. Application build 
                        #       using yarn has been tested for a 35% faster execution when compared to yarn.
                        #npm install --no-optional --production --silent
                        npm install

                        echo "@@@ NPM RUN PROD ( BUILD )"
                        npm run build
                        #yarn
                    """
                }
                prepareForBuildImage()
            }
        }

        stage('Build Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if(!wspace.releaseVersionExists()) {
                        appReleaseTag = osh.buildAppImage(appName, appReleaseTag)
                    } else {
                        appReleaseTag = env.RELEASE_VERSION
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy Unit') {
            steps {
                script {
                    envName=env.DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT
                    osh.deploy(projectName+"-"+envName, appName, envName,appReleaseTag)
                }
            }
        }

    } //stages
} // pipeline

def prepareForBuildImage() {
    sh '''
        echo "Preparing Image contents ..."
        rm -rf tmp
        mkdir -p tmp
        chmod -R 777 tmp
        echo "Compressing files ..."
        tar cvzf tmp.tar.gz client server *.json node_modules index.js build.properties README.md
        cp -pr tmp.tar.gz tmp/ 
        echo "Decompressing files ..."
        cd tmp
        tar xvzf tmp.tar.gz
        rm -fr tmp.tar.gz
        cd ..
        echo "Displaying deployment artifacts ..."
        ls -Rlt tmp/ --ignore=node_modules
    '''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just really dove in and the approach you are using wouldn't be the way I would use.

A lot of the redundant env variables you define and use can simply be extracted from the environment.

The environment block is the suggested way to set env variables, of course doing it within a 'sh' script works but it gets lost and there are a variety of variables being set all over the place. Trying to just keep features/functionality together does help readability. And in improving readability, you personally will start to uncover the unnecessary and/or duplicate or even triplicate methods that are easily lost when the file basically is a hold your breath and jump.

I've taken this file and have gotten rid of about 64% of the code, which is 64% you don't have to read, try to assimilate or even worry about.

To answer your very succinct question after all this;

Clean it up, refactor out redundancy, unnecessary code, prefer the gatekeeper pattern instead of nested conditions, this will keep all code at the same indentation (that's assuming you actually indent, so many don't, so aggravating)

the pattern is

```
if(isNotValid()) return <value if need be>

// if the code is here, the above check passed
```

Start there, challenge yourself to see if you can get this file down 50%.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.